# What happens at the interference of infrared and ultraviolet rays?

Tags: waves, visible-light, wavelength, infrared-radiation

This question occurred to me, and I was wondering what everybody else thought about it. Lets say that an infrared laser and an ultraviolet laser were to intersect at a right angle. What kind of things would happen from there? Would they average out and create a point of visible light? Would they pass through each other as if nothing happened at all? Would their trajectory be effected? Finally, if they did create a point of visible light, would the ray continue on past that point returning to its original wavelength, or would it be permanently altered as it continued along its path?
Thanks for the input! :)

Comment: Are you speaking about the laser beams interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the medium in which they cross is linear, the beams would propagate on as if nothing happened at all. If the medium is [nonlinear](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics), and the electric fields are properly arranged (and probably the beams couldn’t be exactly at right angles), then a visible light ray might arise through a process called difference-frequency generation.